# why is visual studio keep replacing System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll everytime I build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, .net-4.8

I'm building a DLL which goes into the build folder of my Acumatica website, but everytime I build my solution, Visual studio replace an unrelated DLL in my site folder with the same DLL but on another version, which breaks my site.

This is the DLL originaly present in my website

[image]

This is the DLL with which visual studio replace mine:

[image]

I tried just opening this dll so Visual studio just can't replace it, but then it throws an error when I build:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll" to "..\..\..\..\Bin\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed. CUSTOMDEV
```

I finaly added the right DLL in the "references" of visual studio and it solved my problem, but I dont understand why it was so eager to put its own dll there instead of letting mine.

Does someone know why it happened and if there's a way to prevent it ?

TL;DR

I have a website project with a Library project, I'm only building the Library project, but Visual Studio replaces an unrelated DLL which is in my website project with its own version everytime I build the library project.

Comment: Even though this is not a bad post per-se, Its still a little unclear what you are asking, whats being replaced, how its being built ect.

Comment: @MichaelRandall I'm just asking why and how to stop this behaviour, I found a workaround for my problem but I'm curious. Anyway I'll add more details to my question, thanks for the feedback

Comment: I have the exact same problem. This DLL is supposed to come from a NuGet package. Everything in all my projects, every NuGet reference, every binding redirect, in every web.config and every app.config points to version 5.0.0. And yet, on build, somehow version 4.6.0 ends up in the bin folder. It makes no sense. There's something wrong with how Visual Studio is resolving transiitve dependencies.